# Identify duplicate lines in a file without deleting them?

Tags: command-line, sort

I have my references as a text file with a long list of entries and each has two (or more) fields.

The first column is the reference's url; the second column is the title which may vary a bit depending on how the entry was made. Same for third field which may or may not be present.

I want to identify but not remove entries that have the first field (reference url) identical. I know about `sort -k1,1 -u` but that will automatically (non-interactively) remove all but the first hit. Is there a way to just let me know so I can choose which to retain?

In the extract below of three lines that have the same first field (`http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/`), I would like to keep line 2 because it has additional tags (sort, CLI) and delete lines #1 and #3:

```
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/  unique-lines-based-on-the-first-field
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/  Unique lines based on the first field   sort, CLI
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/  Unique lines based on the first field
```

Is there a program to help identify such "duplicates"? Then, I can manually clean up by personally deleting lines #1 and #3?

Comment: I don't quite understand your example... could you give a more simplified version of the input and the expected output?

Comment: Please see if it is clearer now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think that you need something like:

```
for dup in $(sort -k1,1 -u file.txt | cut -d' ' -f1); do grep -n -- "$dup" file.txt; done
```

or:

```
for dup in $(cut -d " " -f1 file.txt | uniq -d); do grep -n -- "$dup" file.txt; done
```

where `file.txt` is your file containing data about you are interested.

In the output you will see the number of the lines and lines where first field is found two or more times.

Comment: Thank you: even  `cut -d " " -f1 file.txt | uniq -d` gives me nice output.

Comment: @DKBose There are probably more possibilities, but I wanted to use and your command also.

Comment: Thanks. The second command is the one I like. You can remove the first. And if you explain the code that would be nice also :)

Answer (score 11):

This is a classical problem that can be solved with the `uniq` command. `uniq` can detect duplicate *consecutive* lines and remove duplicates (`-u`, `--unique`) or keep duplicates only (`-d`, `--repeated`).

Since ordering of duplicate lines is not important for you, you should sort it first. Then use `uniq` to print unique lines only:

```
sort yourfile.txt | uniq -u
```

There is also a `-c` (`--count`) option that prints the number of duplicates for the `-d` option. See the manual page of `uniq` for details.

---

If you really do not care about the parts after the first field, you can use the following command to find duplicate keys and print each line number for it (append another `| sort -n` to have the output sorted by line):

```
 cut -d ' ' -f1 .bash_history | nl | sort -k2 | uniq -s8 -D
```

---

Since you want to see duplicate lines (using the first field as key), you cannot directly use `uniq`. The issue that make automation difficult is that the title parts vary, but a program cannot automatically determine which title should be considered the final one.

Here is an AWK script (save it to `script.awk`) that takes your text file as input and prints all duplicate lines so you can decide which to delete. (`awk -f script.awk yourfile.txt`)

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    # Store the line ($0) grouped per URL ($1) with line number (NR) as key
    lines[$1][NR] = $0;
}
END {
    for (url in lines) {
        # find lines that have the URL occur multiple times
        if (length(lines[url]) > 1) {
            for (lineno in lines[url]) {
                # Print duplicate line for decision purposes
                print lines[url][lineno];
                # Alternative: print line number and line
                #print lineno, lines[url][lineno];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is close to what I want but I need the opposite of `-f, --skip-fields=N (avoid comparing the first N fields). In other words, I want only the first field, the urls, to be considered.

Comment: @DKBose There is a `-w` (`--check-chars`) option to limit to a fixed number of characters, but seeing your example, you have variable first fields. Since `uniq` does not support field selection, you have to use a workaround. I'll include an AWK example since that's easier.

Comment: Yes, I was just looking at `-w` but the length of the first field is variable :(

Comment: @DKBose Please see the latest edit

Comment: I'm getting awk: script.awk: line 4: syntax error at or near [ 
awk: script.awk: line 10: syntax error at or near [
awk: script.awk: line 18: syntax error at or near }

Comment: @DKBose Perhaps the default `awk` implementation of Ubuntu does not support it, try `gawk -f script.awk yourfile.txt` then.

Answer (score 2):

If I read this correctly, all you need is something like

```
awk '{print $1}' file | sort | uniq -c | 
    while read num dupe; do [[ $num > 1 ]] && grep -n -- "$dupe" file; done
```

That will print out the number of the line that contains the dupe and the line itself. For example, using this file:

```
foo bar baz
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/  unique-lines-based-on-the-first-field
bar foo baz
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/  Unique lines based on the first field   sort, CLI
baz foo bar
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/  Unique lines based on the first field
```

It will produce this output:

```
2:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/  unique-lines-based-on-the-first-field
4:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/  Unique lines based on the first field   sort, CLI
6:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/  Unique lines based on the first field
```

To print only the number of the line, you could do

```
awk '{print $1}' file | sort | uniq -c | 
 while read num dupe; do [[ $num > 1 ]] && grep -n -- "$dupe" file; done | cut -d: -f 1
```

And to print only the line:

```
awk '{print $1}' file | sort | uniq -c | 
while read num dupe; do [[ $num > 1 ]] && grep -n -- "$dupe" file; done | cut -d: -f 2-
```

---

**Explanation:**

The `awk` script just prints the 1st space separated field of the file. Use `$N` to print the Nth field. `sort` sorts it and `uniq -c` counts the occurrences of each line.

This is then passed to the `while` loop which saves the number of occurrences as `$num` and the line as `$dupe` and if `$num` is greater than one (so it's duplicated  at least once) it will search the file for that line, using `-n` to print the line number. The `--` tells `grep` that what follows is not a command line option, useful for when `$dupe` can start with `-`.

Answer (score 1):

No doubt the most verbose one in the list, could probably be shorter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import collections
file = "file.txt"

def find_duplicates(file):
    with open(file, "r") as sourcefile:
        data = sourcefile.readlines()
    splitlines = [
        (index, data[index].split("  ")) for index in range(0, len(data))
        ]
    lineheaders = [item[1][0] for item in splitlines]
    dups = [x for x, y in collections.Counter(lineheaders).items() if y > 1]
    dupsdata = []
    for item in dups:
        occurrences = [
            splitlines_item[0] for splitlines_item in splitlines\
                       if splitlines_item[1][0] == item
            ]
        corresponding_lines = [
            "["+str(index)+"] "+data[index] for index in occurrences
            ]
        dupsdata.append((occurrences, corresponding_lines))

    # printing output   
    print("found duplicates:\n"+"-"*17)
    for index in range(0, len(dups)):
        print(dups[index], dupsdata[index][0])
        lines = [item for item in dupsdata[index][1]]
        for line in lines:
            print(line, end = "")


find_duplicates(file)
```

gives on a textfile like:

```
monkey  banana
dog  bone
monkey  banana peanut
cat  mice
dog  cowmeat
```

an output like:

```
found duplicates:
-----------------
dog [1, 4]
[1] dog  bone
[4] dog  cowmeat
monkey [0, 2]
[0] monkey  banana
[2] monkey  banana peanut
```

Once you picked the lines to remove:

```
removelist = [2,1]

def remove_duplicates(file, removelist):
    removelist = sorted(removelist, reverse=True)
    with open(file, "r") as sourcefile:
        data = sourcefile.readlines()
    for index in removelist:
        data.pop(index)
    with open(file, "wt") as sourcefile:
        for line in data:
            sourcefile.write(line)

remove_duplicates(file, removelist)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following sorted `file.txt`:

```
addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/click-to-play-per-element/ ::: C2P per-element
addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/prospector-oneLiner/ ::: OneLiner
askubuntu.com/q/21033 ::: What is the difference between gksudo and gksu?
askubuntu.com/q/21148 ::: openoffice calc sheet tabs (also askubuntu.com/q/138623)
askubuntu.com/q/50540 ::: What is Ubuntu's Definition of a "Registered Application"?
askubuntu.com/q/53762 ::: How to use lm-sensors?
askubuntu.com/q/53762 ::: how-to-use-to-use-lm-sensors
stackoverflow.com/q/4594319 ::: bash - shell replace cr\lf by comma
stackoverflow.com/q/4594319 ::: shell replace cr\lf by comma
wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence ::: ClipboardPersistence
wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence ::: ClipboardPersistence - Ubuntu Wiki
www.youtube.com/watch?v=1olY5Qzmbk8 ::: Create new mime types in Ubuntu
www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hu9JrdSXB8 ::: Change mouse cursor
www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yxfa2fXJ1Wc ::: Mouse cursor size
```

Because the list is short, I can see (after sorting) that there are three sets of duplicates.

Then, for example, I can choose to keep:

```
askubuntu.com/q/53762 ::: How to use lm-sensors?
```

rather than

```
askubuntu.com/q/53762 ::: how-to-use-to-use-lm-sensors
```

But for a longer list this will be difficult. Based on the two answers one suggesting `uniq` and the other suggesting `cut`, I find that this command gives me the output I would like:

```
$ cut -d " " -f1 file.txt | uniq -d
askubuntu.com/q/53762
stackoverflow.com/q/4594319
wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence
$
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with another variant of `cut`. If you are doing de-duplicating work, then line numbers may be very helpful. To print all duplicates, use the `-D` option instead of `-d`.

Comment: I think you better use: `for dup in $(cut -d " " -f1 file.txt | uniq -d); do grep -n $dup file.txt; done` as in my answer. It will give you a better preview about what you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Her is how I solved it:

file_with_duplicates:

```
1,a,c
2,a,d
3,a,e <--duplicate
4,a,t
5,b,k <--duplicate
6,b,l
7,b,s
8,b,j
1,b,l
3,a,d <--duplicate
5,b,l <--duplicate
```

File sorted and deduped by columns 1 and 2:

```
sort -t',' -k1,1 -k2,2 -u file_with_duplicates
```

File sorted only by columns 1 and 2:

```
sort -t',' -k1,1 -k2,2 file_with_duplicates
```

Show  the difference only:

```
diff <(sort -t',' -k1,1 -k2,2 -u file_with_duplicates) <(sort -t',' -k1,1 -k2,2 file_with_duplicates)

 3a4
   3,a,d
 6a8
   5,b,l
```