# How do I print all the usernames that have same UID in `/etc/passwd` by using awk?

Tags: users, awk

How do I print all the usernames that have same UID in `/etc/passwd`?

This is my command

```
$ awk -F: '{print $3, $1}' us.txt | sort   
0 daemon
0 pepe
0 root
2 bin
2 jacinto
3 paco
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identify duplicate lines in a file without deleting them?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/434545/identify-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-without-deleting-them)

Comment: this is my command        awk -F: '{print $3, $1}' us.txt | sort                                     result  0 daemon
0 pepe
0 root
2 bin
2 jacinto
3 paco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a count for each UID, and save UIDs, and then  print those entries whose UIDs have appeared more than once:

```
awk -F: '{count[$3]++; users[$3] = $1 " " users[$3]} END {for (i in count) {if (count[i] > 1) { print users[i] } } }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: did not print anything

Comment: @AniqueAwan there was a typo. It should be `users` at the end, not `user`.

Comment: what ?? i did not understand .. what are you saying ? can you explain me please

Comment: 0 pepe 0 daemon 0 root ....
2 jacinto 2 bin.....
3 paco ....
but uid repeting after every name but i want only one time how i can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the file twice:

```
awk -F: 'FNR==NR{count[$3]++; next}
         count[$3]>1 && !seen[$1] {
               print $1, $3, "("count[$3]" times)"; seen[$1]++
        }' /etc/passwd{,}
```

- First time to keep a counter of how many times each UID appears.
- Second time to print all those values who were noted to appear more than once.

As a one liner:

```
awk -F: 'FNR==NR{count[$3]++; next} count[$3]>1 && !seen[$1] {print $1, $3, "("count[$3]" times)"; seen[$1]++}' /etc/passwd{,}
```

A sample output would be:

```
root 0 (2 times)
```

Comment: well thats work ... But how i can print the users that have same uid.. means  root ,daemon , pepe have the same uid.. so the result have to be like this      0  root,daemos,pepe etc

Comment: Did you run the script? Do it and try to tweak it to show wgat you want. If you cannot, post your attempts and I will help you.

Comment: yes i run the script.. ok later i  will post...  thanks